# Convert NSDate to UTC string and then back to NSDate, the results are not the same

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter, utc

I want to convert NSDate() to UTC date string and then convert this date string back to NSDate, but the results are not the same.

```
func UTCDateStringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return dateString
}
// outputs: "20150520T030303Z"
let dateString = UTCDateStringFromDate(NSDate())

func dateFromUTCDateString(dateString: String) -> NSDate {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"
    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
}
// outputs: "May 20, 2015, 11:03 AM"
dateFromUTCDateString(dateString)
```

As you can see both outputs, when I convert NSDate() to UTC date string, the result is "20150520T030303Z" and then I convert this date string back to NSDate, the result is "May 20, 2015, 11:03 AM". Why the time is not the same? The first is 03:03 and the second is 11:03?

Answer (score 1):

Because if you just println a `NSDate()`

It will log date format in **GMT**,so in your time is **UTC + 8**

So,your code works just well.

Edit:

- There is no timezone of a `NSDate`,it is just a reference of a absolute time.

Comment: So, there is no way to get a UTC NSDate? only the date string?

Comment: A NSDate have no Timezone, if you want it have Timezone, convert it to String as you did before

Comment: But I really need a NSDate with particular timezone. What can I do?